# How to set a value to the additional column of the join table in the Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a three tables:
`product` (id, name)
`image` (id, src)
`product_images` (product_id, image_id, position)
Position field is ordinal number of the product's image.
Product_images is the join table.
Also there are three models in Rails 4:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_images, class_name: "ProductImage"
  has_many :images, through: :product_images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :product_images
  has_many :products, through: :product_images, foreign_key: :product_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_images, allow_destroy: true

end

class ProductImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "product_images"

  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :image

  #has_many   :images
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :image, :allow_destroy => true
  #attr_accessible :position

end
```

In controller:

```
def test
  @pr  = Product.new name: "Super Sofa"
  @imgs = Image.find(19, 20)
  @imgs[0].position = 1
  @imgs[1].position = 2
  @pr.images = @imgs
  @pr.save
end
```

Rails returns this error:
**undefined method `position=' for # Image:0x68696e8**

How can I set position field to the `product_images` table through the `Image` model? Is it possible? Perhaps I have wrong understanding of **accepts_nested_attributes_of**.
 May be the pure SQL is the better way in this case?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
product_images (product_id, image_id, position)
```

You have the attribute of position under product images, which belong to the image.

```
def test
  @pr  = Product.new name: "Super Sofa"
  @imgs = Image.find(19, 20)
  @imgs[0].product_image.first.position = 1
  @imgs[1].product_image.first.position = 2
  @pr.images = @imgs
  @pr.save
end
```

You need to specify which product image that you want to change, because your image has may product images. If you call position , it has to be on product image, unless you do something like this.

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
def position
  self.product_images.first.position
end
end
```

But that would make no sense because then the position attribute should be under the image table not the product-images table. Have a think.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But both of these variants generates an error:<br> `undefined method `position=' for nil:NilClass`<br>
I have tried such code:<br>
    @imgs[0].product_images[0] = ProductImage.new position: 1

This code doesn`t generate errors, but `position` field is empty. For some reason @imgs[0].product_images[0] is `Nil` after assigning.<br>

>>the position attribute should be under the image table not the product-images table<br>

Image may be included by several products, therefore image may has different `position` for each `product`.